# DevTools Failed to Sourcemap Error when a React component is implemented

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, next.js, apollo

I have been developing an web application on Next.js using Apollo
When I am fetching the user data for authentication I was displaying a simple

element to show the user that it is loading in my withAuth HOC which works perfectly fine.

then, I created a react Loader component and wanted to display the loader component instead of the simple paragraph elements which crashed my app and attach an img of the error below.

My GitHub repo is as follows:
https://github.com/AybarsAcar/PortfolioApp

cheers!

[the error message on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHlky.png)

Answer (score 1):

As I have known for a while now, those info logs aren't related to your code/problem.
From the image you shared, tick the "Selected context only".